# Secure Azure Storage from public internet acces

Tags: azure

We got a message from Azure Security center that :

> **Unusual access inspection in a storage account**
>
> Indicates that the access permissions of a storage account have been
>   inspected in an unusual way, compared to recent activity on this
>   account. A potential cause is that an attacker has performed
>   reconnaissance for a future attack.

What is the best method to secure Azure Storage used by Azure Function from public internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your resource in azure portal and then to Firewalls and virtual networks menu.

[image]

There you can find a plethora of options on how to secure your application.

By default the acocnt is open to all networks.

But you can change this option to allow access only to specific virtual networks.

You can also set specific public ips allowed to access the resource.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-virtual-network-integration-for-azure-storage-and-azure-sql/